# Wrong qutation mark in VS Code integrated terminal with Git Bash on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

For example I get **error: no type named â??** instead of **error: no type named ‘**. If I run WSL bash instead of Git Bash in VS Code integrated terminal, then quotation marks are correct. If I run standalone Git Bash there is no problem either. 
I have tried different fonts and themes for integrated terminal with no luck. I think it is related to wrong code page, but I do not know how to change it for Git Bash or VS Code. Thanks in advance.